# Get the data of a ggplot object when its originating function has not returned a "ggplot" object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a package that generates a plot when using `plot(model)`, but the resulting object of storing this call is `NULL`. This happens because the function does not properly return the ggplot object, but instead simply finishes with `p <- ggplot(); print(p)` and a `NULL` object is returned.
I am interested in getting the data because the function also performs many transformations in the process of plotting.

I have tried to get the results manually adding the class, but there is nothing to be passed. Also, `ggplot_build` does not work either, because precisely the resulting object is indeed `NULL`.

I have also tried to generate a replicable example, but in my case, the function does indeed return a ggplot object:

```
g <- function() {
  d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  print(p)
}

g()
figure <- g()
class(figure)
```

So the replicable example using the specific package is this one:

```
library(cjoint)
data("immigrationconjoint")
r <- amce(Chosen_Immigrant ~ Gender, data = immigrationconjoint)
plot(r)
figure <- plot(r)
class(figure)
```

The function is "plot.amce()" at https://github.com/cran/cjoint/blob/777012d7826c8c80b5a01c48f89dd4fee33e984f/R/cjoint.R starting at line 1667.

My question is then whether there is a way to get the data used in the call of ggplot when the resulting function generates a `NULL`.

Thank you,

Comment: In line 2111 of the github page you cited the function calls  `p = ggplot(d, aes(y=pe, x=var, colour=group))` so I assume the data you are looking for is stored within `d`. You might just copy that function into your editor, add a `return(d)` at some appropriate point and thus override the function. It's open source and you can adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: Yes, @Bernhard, thank you. This is my option now. But I was curious about why the toy example returns a ggplot object, whereas the function, that does exactly the same, returns NULL and does not allow to capture the ggplot object inside. Do you have an explanation for that? Any hint?